# Manipulating the value of the rules

Tags: replacement, rule

I have a fitted model given in the code below and I am trying to shift the function to get its maxima in the center ($t=0$). The variable `center[i]` controls the center position of the basis function and therefore I want to shift all the centers of these basis functions (here I have used 2 basis functions).

```
NBasisFun = 2;    
model = Sum[a[i] Exp[-(b[i])^2 (t - center[i])^2], {i, 1, NBasisFun, 1}];
fitPrams = {a[1] -> 6.13531, a[2] -> 0.501507, b[1] -> 4.97662, b[2] -> 1.82646, 
center[1] -> -0.127246, center[2] -> -0.393956};

Plot[model /. fitPrams, {t, -1, 1}]
```

To shift all the basis functions, I find the maxima of the fitted function and the corresponding $t$ value (`PeakLocation`) using `NMaximize` then I create a new model i.e. `PeakShiftedModel` where I add this value to `center[i]`.

```
PeakLocation = t /. Last[NMaximize[model /. fitPrams, t]]
PeakShiftedModel = Sum[a[i] Exp[-(b[i])^2 (t - center[i] + PeakLocation)^2], 
{i, 1, NBasisFun, 1}] /. fitPrams

Plot[PeakShiftedModel, {t, -1, 1}]
```

While this approach works, I want to change directly the fitted parameters by adding the `PeakLocation` to the center positions (`center[i]`) of the fitted parameters `fitPrams`. Something that looks like this:

```
fitPrams = {a[1] -> 6.13531, a[2] -> 0.501507, b[1] -> 4.97662, b[2] -> 1.82646, 
center[1] -> -0.127246 - PeakLocation, center[2] -> -0.393956 - PeakLocation};
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Try `fitPrams /. (center[k_] -> val_) :> (center[k] -> val - PeakLocation)`.

Comment: yes, that seems to work good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fitPrams[[-2 ;;, -1]] = fitPrams[[-2 ;;, -1]] - PeakLocation; 
fitPrams
```

> {a[1] -> 6.13531, a[2] -> 0.501507, b[1] -> 4.97662, b[2] -> 1.82646, 
>    center[1] -> 0.00230586, center[2] -> -0.264404}